# Show a contractible compact subset of $\Bbb{R}^2$ has connected complement.

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $A \subset \Bbb{R}^2$ be compact and contractible. I need to show $\Bbb{R}^2 \setminus A$ is connected. I know since $A$ is a compact subset of the plane, it is closed and bounded thus its complement is open. Do I also need to show its closed to show connectivity or could I appeal to a theorem?

Comment: It is not clear what do you want to accomplish with showing that it is closed.

Comment: I suppose what i meant to say is that the only clopen subsets of the complement are whole space and empty set which would imply its connected @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez

Comment: You have to use some algebraic topology tools. Do you know Alexander duality?

Comment: I do not know Alexander duality, there must be a simpler way to do it lol @MoisheKohan

Comment: OK, what tools of AT do you know?

Comment: Just some basic homotopy theory and fundamental group theory. Borsuk Ulam, Borsuks  Lemma, Jordan curve theorem, hairy ball theorem. @MoisheKohan

Comment: How did you prove Jordan curve theorem?

Comment: @MoisheKohan by first showing $S^2$ minus the curve has in fact only two components then showing the curve is their common boundary.

Comment: Ive been hinted to use the Borsuk Lemma but we are in the real plane not the 2 sphere.. so I dont see that connection..

Comment: You can translate this to a problem on $S^2$ by noting that since $A$ is compact, under stereographic projection it gives a compact subset of $S^2$. Then you can try to show that the complement in $S^2$ is connected.

Comment: @kamills do I use the nullhomotopy lemma together with the Borsuk Lemma? After converting to the unit 2 sphere ?

Comment: @kamills what i was thinking was defining $f: A \to S^$ via the identity map sending elements to themselves then applying the Borsuk lemma?